# Why Angular 2 or Angular 4 use banana brackets? Is there any specific reason for that? Why they won't follow same pattern as Angular 1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, web

I know its not related to any coding but they can follow the same syntax as in Angular 1

```
<input ng-model="hero.name" placeholder="name" type="text">
```

AngulAR 2 and its Greater Version Syntax till now

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name" type="text">
```

If they do so, it would be very helpful for people to adapt change in Angular JS ?

Similarly for `ng-repeat`, they changed to `ngFor`

```
<ul ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items track by myTrackingFunction(n)">
<li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: read [binding syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax)

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are asking to port this way of data-binding back to AngularJS? AngularJS and Angular have different ways of handling HTML. In AngularJS, the HTML had to be accepted by the browser. In Angular, the HTML templates will be pre-processed before going to the browser. You can check yourself with the browser dev tools of your choice

Answer (score 3):

The banana brackets are for double way binding.

See

> #### [Binding syntax:](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax)
>
> Data binding is a mechanism for coordinating what users see, with
> application data values. While you could push values to and pull
> values from HTML, the application is easier to write, read, and
> maintain if you turn these chores over to a binding framework. You
> simply declare bindings between binding sources and target HTML
> elements and let the framework do the work.
>
> Angular provides many kinds of data binding. This guide covers most of
> them, after a high-level view of Angular data binding and its syntax.
>
> Binding types can be grouped into three categories distinguished by
> the direction of data flow: from the *source-to-view*, from
> *view-to-source*, and in the **two-way** sequence: *view-to-source-to-view*.

Comment: This can also achieved in Angular 1

Comment: The binding is old javascript. The syntax is used specifically for Angular

Comment: Then for one way binding in Angular 2

Comment: The javascript doesn't have MVW

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI `[]` is for one way.

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI `()` is for way back.

Answer (score 1):

Banana Brackets... `[()]` that is a standard way of ***two way data-binding*** in angular. It is a getter and setter. `[]` setter while `()` for getter, so combining them to achieve two way data binding for `ngModel`.

Setters `[]` can lead you to have ***one way binding***.

---

Angular *(2,4+)* is a complete rewrite of angular1 as angular has adopted typescript as it's base language and it is completely rewritten with typescript. Typescript has all the latest javascript's feature + types. Which can let you ensure about what type of data flow is in the logic.

But this doesn't stop user to use angularjs, anyone can use as it is also in development and they are trying to find easy way to migrate angularjs to angular.

Comment: In AngularJs, we can also have a two way binding. But in this we are using like {{hero.name}}

Comment: `{{expression}}` it is a expression. this can be used for one way. `ng-model` directive can lead you to achieve two way data binding. Okay! what is the actual question you asked?

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI updated answer too. i hope it will shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

Banana in a box it just a template syntax for Two-Way Data Binding
and it combines the property binding and the event binding.

So **instead of** writing it explicitly:

```
<my-input [text]="val" (textChange)="val=$event"></my-input>
```

We can leverage the **shortened syntax**:

```
<my-input [(text)]="val"></my-input>
```

Why is it named “BANANA IN A BOX”?
The naming assists us in remembering the order of the brackets of the Two-Way Data Binding.

```
[] = box
() = banana.
[()] = banana in a box
```

[Here](https://medium.com/@ofirrifo/custom-angular-component-using-two-way-data-binding-aka-banana-in-a-box-syntax-9eb06b8cfb09) is explanation.